# Can I prevent tslint warning about unused function which is @HostListener annotated

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I have an angular (v6) project and am using tslint (tslint@~5.9.1) in vscode, and I have a function declared like so:

```
@HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
private onWindowMessage(event) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In vscode Tslint (I think) is giving me the warning:
`'onWindowMessage' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)`

The function is only ever triggered by the window's 'message' event and not referenced anywhere else in my code. Obviously this is a frivolous issue, but it is annoying. Could this be a shortcoming of tslint or is there a way to kill this warning?

Comment: Make the method public. It's supposed to be called from the outside of the component class, so it should be public.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. And that kills the tslint warning. Thanks!